# Multi-threading: What happens if you run 2 processes e.g. (x=1, x=2) (x=x++) simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading

What happens if you run 2 processes `x=1`, `x=2` and `x=x++` simultaneously?

Comment: Nobody knows, behavior is undefined

Comment: Processes or threads? If threads, it depends entirely on how you wrote the code.

Comment: If you're asking what happens when multiple threads try to modify the same value then what you're talking about is called a race condition.

Comment: They are processes and x are shared variables. If you run them both at the same time, what result do you get? How does it depend on how one writes the code? One process is (x=1, x=2) and the other process is (x=x+1).

Comment: Thanks David, I'll search it up.

Comment: @Tia: If they're separate processes, how are they sharing `x`?  Define "at the same time".  It's not common for things to happen *simultaneously* on computer hardware.  Generally one happens and then the other.  It only appears simultaneous to humans because we aren't as fast as computers.

Comment: @David: Sorry, I mean process 1 is multithreaded and process 2 runs afterwards.

Comment: @Tia: Separate processes don't share in-memory variables.  I think you're drastically misunderstanding some fundamental concepts which is leading to your confusion on the matter.  Do you have a concrete example of code which is behaving unexpectedly that you could share?

Comment: @David: Sorry, this is just something that I found online and don't understand. I'm going to read up on race condition, sequential consistency and Lamport timestamps. I'm pretty sure I'm just overcomplicating things. Thanks for your help David!

Comment: @David, In fact, it makes sense to say that two events _never_ happen at the same time in computer hardware because, when we're reasoning about parallel computing, the only events that matter are updates to shared variables.  The computer's memory system _always_ serializes updates to any given, physical memory location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any one of the 6 possibilities based of what executes when. 6 possibilities because there are factorial(3) possibilities.

e.g. the order in which your code gets executed can be

```
1. x = 1
2. x++
3. x = 2
```

result will be x = 2

OR it could be

```
1. x = 1
2. x = 2
3. x++
```

result will be x = 3.
(I am assuming your process always executes `x = 1` before `x = 2` because of the order in which you wrote them)

Note that if `x++` executes before any other then it might result in undefined behaviour based on the initialization of `x`.
Map out all 6 possibilities to see what states your code can reach and that should help clarify.

You might want to check out Lamport's clock and sequential consistency.

Comment: Thanks for your help ritratt!

Comment: There is no undefined behavior in java. In this case this is because variables are always zero initialized even if there's race condition. Second x++ is not atomic hence there are a few more options, but since x=1 cannot be executed after x=2 that evens itself out (if you assume x++ is atomic there are only three options)